# Python using a loop to search for N number and return index

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I have been programming for a total of three weeks.  I am stuck on this problem right now:

We will pass you 2 inputs:

A list of numbers

A number, N, to look for

Your job is to loop through the list and find the number specified in the second input. Output the list element index where you find the number.

If N is not found in the list, output -1.

This is what I have so far:

## import and N were provided

```
import sys
N= int(sys.argv[2])
```

## this is also provided

```
numbers= []
for i in sys.argv[1].split(","):
    if(i.isdigit()):
        numbers.append(int(i))
```

## mycode

```
for i in numbers: 
    if N in numbers: 
        print(i)
    elif N not in numbers: 
        print(-1)
```

This outputs the following for the random number inputs:

Program Failed for Input: 1,3,11,42,12 2
Expected Output: -1
Your Program Output: -1
-1
-1
-1
-1

This is not working and returns -1 for every number N that is not in the list numbers.  I have tried using a break statement before and after print, but that stops it from printing at all.  Any suggestions?

Comment: When you are looping through the list, you don't want to check whether the number is in the list (you wouldn't need to loop for that); you want to compare the number to the current item of the list and check whether they match. There is another thing missing from your solution: a counter that tells you the current position, when looping, so you can get the index when there is a match.

Comment: take a look at the wonderful [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to iterate the list by element + index pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your comments and answers.  After messing around with it a bit, this is what ended up providing the proper output:

## My Code:

```
if N in numbers: 
    print (numbers.index(N))
if N not in numbers: 
    print(-1)
```

## Output:

Program Output

Input: 1,3,11,42,12 42
Your Output: 3
Challenge Feedback

Well done!

Comment: Oh, I thought you weren't allowed to use `index` and really had to loop. That's a good solution then. You could use `elif` instead of the second `if`, or `else` if you don't want to be explicit, or even just in one line: `print(numbers.index(N) if N in numbers else -1)`. A different approach would be to use a `try/except` block instead of the two `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
N= int(sys.argv[2])


print "\n"

numbers= []
for i in sys.argv[1].split(","):
    if(i.isdigit()):
        numbers.append(int(i))
        print i 


i = 0


for num in numbers:

    if num == N:
        print "number found at index %d " % (i)

    i+=1
```

run this with `python program_name.py [,x,y,z,l,m,n,] N` where x,y,z,l,m,n are the numbers in the list and N is the number you search ( note the `[,` and `,]` )

Answer (score -1):

```
if N in numbers :
  for num in range(len(numbers)) :
    if numbers[num] == N :
      print(num)
else :
  print(-1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.