# using indexing to search for N number in list and return index

Tags: python

it seems I have the same problem as the below question. but I am not understanding the proposed solution:

[Python using a loop to search for N number and return index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381225/python-using-a-loop-to-search-for-n-number-and-return-index)

in this scenario, the below is provided:

We will pass you 2 inputs:

A list of numbers

A number, N, to look for

Your job is to loop through the list and find the number specified in the second input. Output the list element index where you find the number.

If N is not found in the list, output -1.

This is what I have so far:

(import and N were provided)

```
import sys
N= int(sys.argv[2])

(this is also provided)
```

```
numbers= []
for i in sys.argv[1].split(","):
    if(i.isdigit()):
        numbers.append(int(i))
```

*the code works with the below

```
if N in numbers:
    print(numbers.index(N))
else:
    print(-1)
```

but in this code, shouldn't it read?:

```
if N[1] in numbers:

    print(numbers.index(N[1]))

else:
    print(-1)
```

the automatically generated inputs and correct answer are:
Input: 1,3,11,42,12 42 Your Output: 3

so after all this, the problem I am having understanding is how just looking for N is telling the code to look for the second input.

if the auto inputs are [11,42] , wouldn't (n[1])? tell it to use this value?

if anyone can please help clarify my understanding of this simple indexing problem it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is the following

```
if N in numbers:                  # check if the number N in the list of numbers at all
    print(numbers.index(N))       # the index method searchs in the numbers list for the first entry matching the number N and returns its index.
else:
    print(-1)
```

since `N` is defined as int(x) it is no list, that you can index with N[x]. the [x] part tells the interpreter to search for the x'th entry of a iterable which you don't want do do here.

Comment: thank you, but in this prompt, it specifically asks for the second N value (N=[x,y] (N is a list of 2 random numbers) how is just using N going to confirm the second value is used? (in this case the Y) ? this formula I think should only work if the first value of N (or X) does not exist in the numbers list

Comment: You wrote N = int(arg...). The result of that will never be a list (see [int() method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/int)). So i gues you have gotten something mixed up. If you can print(argv) to us, so we see all the input, i may be able to help you understand what happens more clearly. If N was a list, then either numbers would have to contain lists as well, or yes, you would have to pick an entry(e.g. N[1]) for it to work

Comment: If you refer to "find the number specified in the second input", this just refers to the second input of argv, which is an array of arguments for the program. that in this case looks something like argv=[program_name, "1,2,33,42,12", 2] where the last entry is your number N